# SQL ROUND - What is the actual reason for arithmetic overflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, double, decimal, rounding

I've been tasked with debugging some of our older code at work and came across an issue. The code is written in VB6, we have a function called `RoundIt()` that takes in a value and then rounds it to 2 decimal places. Surprisingly, the function (and I don't have much experience in VB6 so I'm assuming it might just be a limitation of the language) builds a SQL string to execute in order to round the value.

So in the code we have a double type variable that I'll call `myVal`. In this particular case we are getting an error because the value of `myVal` is `0.997721736173984`, and the string built becomes

```
 SELECT ROUND(0.997721736173984, 2) as RoundedNum
```

which results in the message "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric." From what I understand this is due to the value trying to be rounded to 1 but unable to do so because now the data type that is being returned is different from what was input in the ROUND function, and those must be the same.

My question is, since this is a dynamically built SQL string, it's not like we're declaring a SQL variable with a data type and using it in the ROUND function, we are just building the string - so **what exactly is the data type of `0.997721736173984` by default? And what then is the data type of what is attempting to be returned?** I'm guessing a decimal (not sure of precision or scale), and that the precision or scale are now different when it attempts to return the rounded value, but I'd just like to be sure.

I am not asking to avoid the arithmetic overflow, or determine differences on different servers, so this question is not a duplicate of what was suggested. My question is what data types are input/output from a dynamically built SQL string, and why does that cause an arithmetic overflow error (if according to the comment below, they are of the same data type).

Comment: Are you sure it is `MS SQL Server`? `ROUND` requires 2 arguments.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add that part, updated question.

Comment: what version of SQL server? When I tossed your code into SQL 2012, it doesn't run. That said, my thought here is that SQL Server is expecting something like numeric(x,y), and that the total number of digits is greater than x.

Comment: `NUMERIC(15,15)` **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447840)**

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 for the demo, what about the rounded value though? Why is there an arithmetic overflow if they are the same data type?

Comment: this seems to work: `SELECT cast(ROUND(cast(0.997721736173984 as numeric(16,15)), 2) as numeric(3,2)) as RoundedNum`

Comment: Don't fix the query, fix the function - it's wasteful and pointless. I'm 99% sure VB6 has a Round() function - at least VBA does. If it doesn't, you can write one easily, either using basic math or by formatting the value to two decimal places and then converting it back to a number. Don't do a server round-trip every time you need to perform a basic math operation.

Comment: @EdGibbs I completely agree, this is old code that I was tasked with debugging, so absolutely I would not have done it this way.

Comment: In a roundabout way the question is how do I solve this, but the immediate question I'm asking is why is this arithmetic overflow, and what are the data types causing that error.

Comment: No worries @Goose - I was worried you had a case of "developer tunnel vision". We all suffer from it sometimes :) And you're correct that this is an interesting question on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute this code:

```
select 0.097721736173984 RoundedNum
into #temp

exec tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#temp'
```

You will find that it is interpreting your literal number as a numeric(15,15).

```
Column_name Type    Computed  Length Prec  Scale Nullable  TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource  Collation
----------- ------- --------- ------ ----- ----- --------- ------------------- --------------------- ---------
RoundedNum  numeric no        9      15    15    no        (n/a)               (n/a)                 NULL
```

This means you can only use 15 digits and all 15 must be to the right of the decimal.  When you round this number, it no longer fits in the data type so an error is returned.

You can fix it by converting the literal explicitly.  Such as:

```
select round(convert(float,0.997721736173984),2) RoundedNum
```

You can choose whatever data type you want it to be as long as it captures all your expected significant digits.  `Float` gives you the greatest flexibility in range, but with a trade-off of potential loss of accuracy.  If you know that all your digits that you will be rounding will be < 1 and no more than 15 digits, then a `numeric(16,15)` will hold your original and rounded number.  When using numeric types, you just have to consider the range that your numbers will fall in and make sure that you have allocated enough space to hold all your possible results.

Here is some more useful information on how SQL Server resolves numeric data types in expressions:

[Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Brian, I was looking for something I could execute to determine the data type and this definitely helps. It makes sense that the rounded number will not have the same data type... do you by chance know what the data type of the rounded number would be?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178550.aspx) function to find the data type.

```
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(x.y, 'BaseType')   AS DataType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(x.y, 'Precision')  AS Precision,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(x.y, 'Scale')      AS Scale
FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (0.997721736173984)
    ) AS x(y)
;
```

In this case you have a numeric(15, 15).  Because all the available space is allocated to the scale you cannot round to 1.

Explicitly setting the data type, using [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx), will fix your issue.

```
    SELECT
        ROUND(CAST(0.997721736173984 AS NUMERIC(16, 15)), 2)
```